Are quasi-sets (and therefore Schrödinger logic(s)) studied by mathematicians or are they purely in the domain of philosophers?
Context:
I'm a fan of different kinds of logic. I'm conflicted about whether different logics actually exist beyond, say, a philosophical oddity.
The Question:

Are quasi-sets (and therefore Schrödinger logic(s)) studied by mathematicians or are they purely in the domain of philosophers?

Clarifying Thoughts:
Aren't mathematicians philosophers in some sense?
Well, yes, and if they study this stuff, they're set theorists and/or logicians, probably, so even more so than others.
So, what am I really asking?
I am wondering - despite my better judgement (due to experience, see the downvotes) - about how "legitimate" quasi-sets are as actual, reputable mathematics.
I have Wikipedia and some articles I don't understand yet, readily available on Google scholar.  This is niche stuff, I suppose, so citations aren't the strongest indication.
Why the proxy question, then?
Because mathematics is what I am trained in.
Motivation:
I don't want to end up a crank by studying things that might be questionable on a superficial level without due caution.

I care about quality questions.  If this gets shot down as a poor question, I'm sorry, but I hope I could understand this stuff better either way.
Thank you.

We study quasiparticles and other emergent phenomenon already so I don't really think Schrödinger's philosophical concerns are warranted. Personally I share his monistic disposition but it is impractical to consider everything the same thing if we're to do science so I reject it for pragmatic reasons. Philosophers and mathematicians do love semantics though so I can see the appeal of new linguistic concepts to better capture the nature of reality.

The answer is in your linked wiki article. It is part of set-theory, a branch of mathematics. Do a search for the word Krause in the article. You are correct that it is niche, but modern. Read about Godel's incompleteness theorem too for good measure.

Thank you. I'd like a more reliable source than Wikipedia, though, @vallev.
